# Redirect mobile browser in apache but allow them to view full pages

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, redirection, mobile-devices

I know how to redirect browsers based on user-agent to the mobile site.

However I am having trouble allowing mobile users to view more then one version of a full pages.

Here is the scenario:

- Mobile user comes into the site
- User-agent is detected and redirected to the mobile site accordingly
- User views a html page but wants to view the full version
- User clicks the url with a ?ver=full parameter
- This prevents the user from being redirected to the mobile site again
- While on the full site the user clicks another link, they want to stay on the full version but because the link does not have the ?ver=full parameter they get redirected to the mobile site.

Note that all these pages are html (not php/asp)  so this logic has to be done in Apache

Idears?

Comment: I may only suggest looking forward `[CO]` flag (cookies); http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code to your application to write cookies into clients browser, this will help you to determine which page user wants to see :)

Comment: These pages are all in html so I don't have an application language to work with